# Merge calc() with LESS CSS

Tags: css, less

I have a LESS variable containing a CSS `calc()` expression and want to use this variable inside another `calc()` expression. The CSS specification allows nested `calc()` expressions, but not all browers support this (IE/Edge).

Because nested `calc()` expressions essentially have no real use (they are a side effect of using preprocessor variables), I wonder if it's possible to merge them into a single expression using LESS.

By example, I want this:

```
@var1: ~"calc(5rem / 10px)";
@var2: ~"calc(50px + "@var1~")";
```

To compile into:

```
calc(50px + (5rem / 10px))
```

Instead of this:

```
calc(50px + calc(5rem / 10px))
```

Comment: In short, no, Less has absolutely no idea of what that `calc` thing is (especially after you put it into `~""`). That's the reason to not have such `calc` expression as values in variables. You could use `clean-css` though and if I'm not mistaken it should move redundant `calc` away under some of more aggressive options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a kind of "dirty trick" using the LESS `replace()` function:

```
@var2: ~"calc(50px + "replace(@var1, "calc", "")~")";
```

Note that if the child `calc()` expression contains other variables, it only works when they are interpolated:

```
@var1: 5rem;
@var2: ~"calc(@{var1} / 10px)";
@var3: ~"calc(50px + "replace(@var2, "calc", "")~")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you potentially split the first var into two?  For instance:

```
@var1a: 5rem / 10px;
@var1: calc(@var1a);
```

Where:

- `@var2a: ~"calc(50px + "@var1~")";` produces `calc(50px +  calc(0.5rem) )`
- `@var2b: ~"calc(50px + @{var1a})";` produces `calc(50px + 0.5rem)`

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to accomplish here. I don't want the inner calc() expression to get evaluated. I want it to be part of parent expression; to merge it as one.